# How to pre-select a radio button in jQuery

Tags: jquery, select, radio-button

I want to pre-select the first radio button in the following set:

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" value="0" name="serviceNoteType[1]">
<input type="radio" value="1" name="serviceNoteType[1]">
```

**jQuery**

```
var i = 1; // for sake of this example
$('[name="serviceNoteType\\['+ i +'\\]"]').prop('checked', true);
```

The result is that the second radio button gets selected and I want the first one selected. How to I target the first radio button?

Comment: And why not just add a `checked` attribute to the one you want to check ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `.first()` to your selector:

```js
var i = 1; // for sake of this example
$('[name="serviceNoteType\\['+ i +'\\]"]').first().prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" value="0" name="serviceNoteType[1]">
<input type="radio" value="1" name="serviceNoteType[1]">
```

Comment: Cool @j08681 -- I did not know that. I'll give it a try now and post back.

Comment: Awesome...that did the trick. Thanks @j08691 -- I learned something new (which is cool). So I assume `.second()` and `.third()` etc. all work as well.

Comment: @H.Ferrence - But again, why "pre-select" with jQuery, why not just edit the HTML ?

Comment: @H.Ferrence - there's a `.first()` and `.last()`, but for anything in between you can use `.eq()` or `:eq()`. See the jQuery documentation for more info.

Comment: "why "pre-select" with jQuery, why not just edit the HTML" the reason is that the underlying CMS does not open itself up to give me the ability to pre-select the radio. Please don't comment on getting a new CMS @adeneo -- wish I could but I'm 1-and-half years into this CMS and cannot unravel it at this time.

Comment: Excellent insight into the jQuery properties @j08681. Thanks   million!

Answer (score 1):

More shorter form. Try this:

```
$("input:radio:first").attr('checked', true);
```

Comment: Ok, thanks @Riad. Given the complexities in the naming convention for my radio buttons (due to the underlying CMS I am using) I need to use (at)j08691's answer

Answer (score -1):

The names need to be different. Your selector will only check the last element rendered of that name.

```
$('[name="serviceNoteType\\['+ i +'\\]"]:first-child').prop('checked', true);
```

Untested so the syntax may be slightly off but should give you the idea.

Comment: But isn't that how radio buttons differentiate which elements get selected @sareed?

Comment: You are selecting by `name=` since they share the same name it will select the last one rendered. You could do an `each()` and check for value 0 I guess or select first-child etc.

Comment: @sareed - but using the same name for groups of radio buttons is how they work, and what makes them toggle between selections. If you have different names for all the radio buttons, it no longer works as expected.